# Practical way to handle many base64-encoded images in javascript (client-side)?

Tags: javascript, base64, jspdf, pdfkit

I'm building a a website which allows a user to download a personalized pdf. I'm trying to use a javascript library for pdf generation, either [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) or [pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org/). Neither library can use paths to include images in the browser. They need a base64-encoded data URI. Bummer, I have to include many images. These images are stored on the server.

I'm looking for a way to deal with this. I was thinking of batch encoding all my images, and storing the corresponding strings in a json file, which I would then read from when I need to insert an image. I can't do this manually because even a single string chokes my editor. I also can't store the encoded strings in a database, as I have none.

I understand this question isn't very precisely framed. Suggestions to improve it are welcome.

Comment: from pdfkit documentation : Just pass an image path, buffer, **or** data uri with base64 encoded data to the image

Comment: @NicolòCozzani In practice, neither the path nor the buffer worked when using pdfkit in the browser. There are issues on github about that which don't seem to have been solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, the most straightforward way I can think of would be to create a base64 string from the `onchange` event of a file input, and pass the file to the `onload` event of the HTML Filereader api.

html

```
<input type="file" onchange="selectFile(this.value)">
```

javascript

```
selectFile(event: Event | any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
            this.file = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Then you would pass `this.file` to your api, or call your api directly from `reader.onload`

Comment: I forgot to write that my images are stored on the server, not uploaded by the user. I'll edit my question accordingly.